# selection of the search range QtableWidget

Tags: pyqt

please tell me how you can implement group allocation in QTableWidget PyQt5 in two categories (2 columns), the functions (edit) and (setCurrentItem) take only 1 value, ignoring the subsequent ones, thank you for your help. P.S. I'm a noob in this business while I'm studying, do not judge strictly. I know that it is impossible to change the generated code, just a working example.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1920, 1000)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 131, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setInputMask("")
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("1")
        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.add1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 131, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setInputMask("")
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText("4")
        self.lineEdit_2.textChanged.connect(self.add2)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 0, 1720, 1000))
        Row = 35
        self.row = Row
        Col = 7
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(Row)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(Col)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(237)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1920, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        
        
        for column in range(Col):
            for row in range(Row):
                s = self.lineEdit.setText("")
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(s)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, item)
    
                
        for a in range(7):
            for b in range(Row):
                c = self.lineEdit_2.setText("")
                i1 =  QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(c)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(a, b, i1)
                
    def add1(self, s):
        for row in range(self.row):
            if self.tableWidget.item(row,0).text() == s:
                self.tableWidget.editItem(self.tableWidget.item(row, 0))
            
                
    def add2(self, c):
        itims = self.tableWidget.findItems(c, QtCore.Qt.MatchContains)
        if itims: 
            self.tableWidget.setCurrentItem(itims[0])

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You want to do batch insert? based on what mouse selection?

Comment: no, I want all the elements I'm looking for in the table to be highlighted, not just the 1st one.

Comment: What are the elements you are looking for?

Comment: there are 2 lineEdit in the 1st there is a search for the first column, in the second there is a search for the 4th column

Comment: See [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20693470/search-find-functionality-in-qtableview)

Comment: almost, it should loop through the entire column and highlight the desired rows

Comment: I think looping is a bad choice for searching, you should probably create a model yourself and implement the searching in the model, then update the view. `QTabelWidget` is just for simple use cases.